# sql merge rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need help to join colum on the same table, i have one table like this :

```
mat   id      name            date          time
4   138644  YACINE          20160201    130938 entry
4   138645  YACINE          20160201    204033 leave
4   149540  YACINE          20160223    80614
4   149541  YACINE          20160223    160224
31  131905  BENHAOUA        20160118    80459  entry
31  131906  BENHAOUA        20160118    154738 leave
31  485939  BENHAOUA        20160406    54113
31  486091  BENHAOUA        20160406    132152
```

if you can see for each name (mat) i have two line for the same date, the first date reprent entry time and the second leave time, i want to have only one ligne for same name and same date with entry and leave time like this

```
mat  name      date        entry   leave
4   YACINE     20160201   130938   204033
4   YACINE     20160223    80614   160224
31  BENHAOUA   20160118    80459   154738
31  BENHAOUA   20160406    54113   132152
```

i try with inner join in the same table but results was false, i try this :

```
select a.id, a.matricule, a.nom,a.edate, a.etime as entree, b.etime as sortie  
from shift1 a
inner join shift2016 b on a.matricule=b.matricule and a.EDATE=b.EDATE and a.etime<>b.etime 
order by  matricule
```

Comment: La column "time" contient le temps et la chaine de character "entry" et "leave" ?

Comment: If you have always the same `date`, you can use aggregation, `MAX` is the leave date and `MIN` is the entry date

Comment: @Benoît oui chaque ligne est dupliqué deux fois, du coup la colonne time sur la 1ere ligne c'est le temps d'entrer et sur la 2eme ligne le temps de sortie, moi je veux combiner le tout sur une même ligne, donc enlever la duplication des lignes

Comment: @DouraydTLILI how ?

Comment: Is there a flag for entry and leave or should we assume the 1,3,5 etc are entries and 2,4,6 etc are leaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below sample should produce the output you require. This is achieved using pivot operator.

```
declare @tbl table(mat int,id int,name varchar(20)
,date int,time int)

insert into @tbl
values(4,138644,'YACINE',20160201,130938)
,(4,138645,'YACINE',20160201,204033)
,(4,149540,'YACINE',20160223,80614)
,(4,149541,'YACINE',20160223,160224)
,(31,131905,'BENHAOUA',20160118,80459)
,(31,131906,'BENHAOUA',20160118,154738)
,(31,485939,'BENHAOUA',20160406,54113)
,(31,486091,'BENHAOUA',20160406,132152)


select *, case when ROW_NUMBER()
over(partition by mat,date order by id) % 2 <> 0 then 'Entry' else 'Leave' 
end as [status] 
into #temp
from
@tbl

select mat,name,date,Entry,Leave 
from
(select mat,name,date,time,status 
from 
#temp)t
pivot
(max(time) for status in([Entry],[Leave]))p

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :-

```
SELECT MAT
    ,NAME
    ,DATE
    ,MIN(TIME) AS entry
    ,MAX(TIME) AS leave
FROM Persons
GROUP BY mat
    ,NAME
    ,DATE
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment your query would be:

```
SELECT mat
    ,name
    ,DATE
    ,MIN(TIME) AS entry
    ,MAX(TIME) AS leave
FROM shift1
GROUP BY mat
    ,name
    ,DATE
```

Comment: doesn't work, it give me this 
 4 124371 KADA YACINE  20160103 81739 81739
4 124372 KADA YACINE  20160103 160557 160557
13 124384 DERARDJA ABDELHALIM 20160103 80304 80304
13 124385 DERARDJA ABDELHALIM 20160103 154702 154702

Comment: yes you need to remove the id, i update the query accordingly